# emailJS POST https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send 400 reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-services, http-status-code-400

I have this problem 400. I use Emailjs i put the good id but form
doesn't send. I don't understand why.I think is the problem with emailjs.min.js

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrOfz.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15FBr.png)

[email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQPnF.png)

Thank you for yours answers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I looked at your index.html and I only see where you passed in your user ID. Can you post the part where you have to pull the form data from the html inputs and append them to a new Form object? This is more or less the main side of the code, I used jQuery to handle it. Example.

```
 $('#contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent reload
    
    let formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append('service_id', 'default_service');
    formData.append('template_id', 'template_mezfpy6');
    formData.append('user_id', 'user_ID');
 
    $.ajax('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send-form', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false, // auto-detection
        processData: false // no need to parse formData to string
    }).done(function() {
        console.log('Your mail is sent!');
    }).fail(function(error) {
        alert('Oops... ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30839551)